# How can we use jasmine, jasmine.ConsoleReporter, require.js and backbone together

Tags: requirejs, jasmine

I'm struggling to get jasmine along with it's ConsoleReporter working within a backbone application using require.js. I have seen [Check Backbone/requireJs project with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174053/check-backbone-requirejs-project-with-jasmine) but that hardcodes the libraries (which is something that I'd prefer to avoid).

In my backbone application I have created test function (I'd prefer to keep it there to test interactions between models):

```
test = function () {
    require(['js/test/run'], function () {});
}
```

and run.js (I get the console.log "should" fine, but don't get anything to do with the failed test):

```
define(["jasmine", "jasmineConsoleReporter"],
function (jasmine, ConsoleReporter) {

    describe('hello', function () {
        it('should be true', function () {
            console.log('should');
            expect(true).toEqual(true);
        });
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new ConsoleReporter(console.log));

    jasmine.getEnv().execute();

    //return tests;
}
);
```

The shim for jasmine and jasmineConsoleReporter are:

```
jasmine: {
    exports: "jasmine"
},
jasmineConsoleReporter: {
    deps: ['jasmine'],
    exports: "getJasmineRequireObj"
}
```

And the source for jasmineConsoleReporter can be found at https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/console/console.js

I'm guessing that the console reporter isn't being constructed correctly because I get the 'should' in the console and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try my setup:

https://github.com/wojciechszela/jasmine-requirejs-jscover

Adding backbone to it (or any other lib) should be easy.